# Codeigniter REST API no me responde

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, api, rest

Buenas tardes!
Estoy haciendo una aplicación que emplea un sistema api rest con Codeigniter REST API.
He creado la función de registro de usuarios, y haciendo pruebas con postman, todo perfecto, te puedes registrar bien y no da problemas. Esta api está en http://api.midominio.com.

Después tengo una app web, con un formulario de registro, que por AJAX llama a api.midominio/registration/register y le envía los parámetros post del formulario.

Esta app web está en web.midominio

El código que empleo para hacer la llamada a la api es este:

```
<script>
    $("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
        $.post("http://api.midominio.com/registration/register",
            $("#form_registro").serialize(),
            function(data,status)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
        );
    });

</script>
```

Cuando hago click en el botón, este me llama a la api y esta da un 200 OK pero no me devuelve ninguna respuesta. Por ejemplo, si los campos están vacíos debería recibir un JSON con error: true y feedback: "Rellena todos los campos".
Pero mirando en el inspector de chrome no me muestra nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

Añadirnedo un header en el código php que devuelve la respuesta, que de permiso a un origen externo, en este caso mi app web:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://midominio.com");
```